# How to make users get points when using Rate module to rate content?

Tags: 7, userpoints, rating

I'm using the [Rate](https://www.drupal.org/project/rate) module to allow the visitors to rate content. I need the author of the contents get point based in the votes provided for the rate module.

There are plenty of modules to allow the author to get points but I'm looking for one which works fine with the [Rate](https://www.drupal.org/project/rate) module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try the [Voting Rules](http://drupal.org/project/voting_rules) module. It works with voting_api, the rate module uses voting_api too, so it should solve your problem. Unfortunately not so well maintained module, so at least this [patch](http://drupal.org/node/1810836) need. But you can try it without patch, if it won't work, it will not because of that patch.

Comment: The Voting Rules and User Points modules do the job.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [User Points](http://drupal.org/project/userpoints) module.

> This module provides an API for users to gain or lose points for
>   performing certain actions on your site.

Comment: But I still need another module to let the **Rate** module to hook into **User Points**. Am I right? Like this one (this is only for D6) http://drupal.org/project/userpoints_votingapi

Comment: Try making a custom module there is a plenty of User Points `hooks` available.

Comment: I get it by using the http://drupal.org/project/voting_rules module.

Answer (score 0):

To award (user) points based on the votes provided by the [Rate](https://www.drupal.org/project/rate) module, you should use a combination of these often used modules to add (or subtract) user points when some node is voted up (or down):

- [Voting API](https://www.drupal.org/project/votingapi).
- [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules).
- [Voting Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/voting_rules) (attention: alfa version only).
- [User Points](https://www.drupal.org/project/userpoints).

It's also the approach used in the [Answers](https://www.drupal.org/project/answers) module (disclosure: I'm a co-maintainer of it), i.e. within its submodule "Answers Userpoints", which also uses the [Rate](https://www.drupal.org/project/rate) module). If you agree, read on ... (it only requires 4 custom rules if you have the above modules in place, no custom coding needed).

## Required Rules

To handle all variations of voting, you need 4 rules (only!), which cover these 4 cases:

- a node is upvoted.
- an upvote for a node is canceled (= no longer upvoted).
- a node is downvoted.
- a downvote for a node is canceled (= no longer downvoted).

Below are the required rules, for each of these cases (use the Rules UI to import them in your own site, after you enabled the required modules mentioned above). These rules use a content type with machine name `answers_question` (adapt this name to fit your own machine name).

Have a close look at how user points are added (or subtracted), and also who gains (or looses) those points. Obviously, the actual amounts of userpoints can be adapted in those rules to fit your own needs (note: if you don't want to "charge" a downvoter for downvoting, then simply ignore the Rules Actions related to user `vote:user`).

#### Upvote a node

The rule below will grant +5 user points for an upvote (to the author of the node):

```
{ "rules_voteup_question" : {
    "LABEL" : "voteup_question",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "TAGS" : [ "answers" ],
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "voting_rules", "userpoints_rules" ],
    "ON" : { "voting_rules_insert_node" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "node_is_of_type" : {
          "node" : [ "node" ],
          "type" : { "value" : { "answers_question" : "answers_question" } }
        }
      },
      { "voting_rules_condition_check_vote_value" : { "vote" : [ "vote" ], "value" : "1" } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "userpoints_action_grant_points" : {
          "user" : [ "node:author" ],
          "points" : "5",
          "tid" : "0",
          "entity" : [ "" ],
          "description" : "Receive upvote to [node:type-name] \u0022[node:title]\u0022",
          "operation" : "QuestionUpvoteReceived",
          "reference" : "By uid=[vote:uid], for [node:type-name] to q=\u003Ca href=\u0022\/node\/[node:nid]\u0022\u003E[node:title]\u003C\/a\u003E",
          "display" : "1",
          "moderate" : "default"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

#### Cancel the upvote a node

The rule below will grant -5 (= remove +5) user points for a cancelled upvote (to the author of the node):

```
{ "rules_voteup_question_cancel" : {
    "LABEL" : "voteup_question_cancel",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "TAGS" : [ "answers" ],
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "voting_rules", "userpoints_rules" ],
    "ON" : { "voting_rules_delete_node" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "node_is_of_type" : {
          "node" : [ "node" ],
          "type" : { "value" : { "answers_question" : "answers_question" } }
        }
      },
      { "voting_rules_condition_check_vote_value" : { "vote" : [ "vote" ], "value" : "1" } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "userpoints_action_grant_points" : {
          "user" : [ "node:author" ],
          "points" : "-5",
          "tid" : "0",
          "entity" : [ "" ],
          "description" : "Unupvote [node:type-name] \u0022[node:title]\u0022",
          "operation" : "QuestionUpvoteCancelled",
          "reference" : "By uid=[vote:uid], for [node:type-name] to q=\u003Ca href=\u0022\/node\/[node:nid]\u0022\u003E[node:title]\u003C\/a\u003E",
          "display" : "1",
          "moderate" : "default"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

#### Downvote a node

The rule below will subtract -2 (grant -2) user points for a downvote (to the author of the node) ... **AND** also -1 user point for the voter:

```
{ "rules_votedown_question" : {
    "LABEL" : "votedown_question",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "TAGS" : [ "answers" ],
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "voting_rules", "userpoints_rules" ],
    "ON" : { "voting_rules_insert_node" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "node_is_of_type" : {
          "node" : [ "node" ],
          "type" : { "value" : { "answers_question" : "answers_question" } }
        }
      },
      { "voting_rules_condition_check_vote_value" : { "vote" : [ "vote" ], "value" : "-1" } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "userpoints_action_grant_points" : {
          "user" : [ "node:author" ],
          "points" : "-2",
          "tid" : "0",
          "entity" : [ "" ],
          "description" : "Receive downvote to [node:type-name] \u0022[node:title]\u0022",
          "operation" : "QuestionDownvoteReceived",
          "reference" : "By uid=[vote:uid], for [node:type-name] to q=\u003Ca href=\u0022\/node\/[node:nid]\u0022\u003E[node:title]\u003C\/a\u003E",
          "display" : "1",
          "moderate" : "default"
        }
      },
      { "userpoints_action_grant_points" : {
          "user" : [ "vote:user" ],
          "points" : "-1",
          "tid" : "0",
          "entity" : [ "" ],
          "description" : "Issue downvote to [node:type-name] \u0022[node:title]\u0022",
          "operation" : "QuestionDownvoteIssued",
          "reference" : "From uid=[node:author:uid], for [node:type-name] to q=\u003Ca href=\u0022\/node\/[node:nid]\u0022\u003E[node:title]\u003C\/a\u003E",
          "display" : "1",
          "moderate" : "default"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

#### Cancel the downvote a node

The rule below will grant +2 (= remove -2) user points for a cancelled downvote (to the author of the node) ... **AND** also +1 user point for the voter:

```
{ "rules_votedown_question_cancel" : {
    "LABEL" : "votedown_question_cancel",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "TAGS" : [ "answers" ],
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "voting_rules", "userpoints_rules" ],
    "ON" : { "voting_rules_delete_node" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "node_is_of_type" : {
          "node" : [ "node" ],
          "type" : { "value" : { "answers_question" : "answers_question" } }
        }
      },
      { "voting_rules_condition_check_vote_value" : { "vote" : [ "vote" ], "value" : "-1" } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "userpoints_action_grant_points" : {
          "user" : [ "node:author" ],
          "points" : "2",
          "tid" : "0",
          "entity" : [ "" ],
          "description" : "Cancel downvote to [node:type-name] \u0022[node:title]\u0022",
          "operation" : "QuestionDownvoteCancelled",
          "reference" : "By uid=[vote:uid], for [node:type-name] to q=\u003Ca href=\u0022\/node\/[node:nid]\u0022\u003E[node:title]\u003C\/a\u003E",
          "display" : "1",
          "moderate" : "default"
        }
      },
      { "userpoints_action_grant_points" : {
          "user" : [ "vote:user" ],
          "points" : "1",
          "tid" : "0",
          "entity" : [ "" ],
          "description" : "Withdraw downvote to [node:type-name] \u0022[node:title]\u0022",
          "operation" : "QuestionDownvoteWithdrawn",
          "reference" : "From uid=[node:author:uid], for [node:type-name] to q=\u003Ca href=\u0022\/node\/[node:nid]\u0022\u003E[node:title]\u003C\/a\u003E",
          "display" : "1",
          "moderate" : "default"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```